# React useMemo is not caching results

Tags: react-hooks

I have simple React app in Typescript and I am trying to utilize `useMemo()`, but is not working.

`useMemo`, if I understand correctly, should not invoke expensive operation if the input argument is equal to already calculated argument.

```
const memoizedResult = useMemo(() => multiply(data), [data]);
```

But in my case is expensive operation always called and result is not retrieved from cache.

Input value is the same `444`, result is the same `888`. Operation is called 20 times. Should be 1.

Check results in console:
[image]

Demo:

```
import React, { FC, useMemo } from "react";

function App() {
    return <table><tbody>
        {[...Array(20).keys()].map(it => {
            return <CachedRow key={it} data={444}></CachedRow>
        })}
    </tbody></table>
}

export default App;

const CachedRow: FC<{ data: number; }> = ({ data = 1 }) => {
    const memoizedResult = useMemo(() => multiply(data), [data]);
    return (<tr>
        <td>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>{memoizedResult}</td>
    </tr>);
};

function multiply(a: number): string {
    console.log('expensive multiply', a);
    return (a * 2).toString();
}
```

Comment: Do you expect it to serve from cache after the first `<CacheRow />` for the rest of the 19 components? if so that's not going to work, hooks are independent per component. If one of `<CacheRow />` re-renders with the same `props.data` `useMemo` will return the last cached value

Comment: @AsafAviv Yes, I was expecting (or just trying to expect) that cache is based on type and value so all components (rows in my case) rendered with same value will have result prepared. But it seems is not that case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144467/understanding-of-usememo-does-usememo-actually-memoize