# Understanding of useMemo (does useMemo actually memoize?)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to figure out if `useMemo` has a cache table that maps dependencies with results.

Take a look at this example:

```
const [a, setA] = useState(0);

const aSquare = useMemo(() => {
  console.log("recalculating aSquare value");
  return a ** 2;
}, [a]);
```

React documentation of `useMemo` says:

> `useMemo` is a React Hook that lets you cache the result of a calculation between re-renders.

But the Wikipedia page for memoization says:

> Memoization is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls to pure functions and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again.

If we run the sample and play with the value of `a` by calling `setA` with different numbers we'll see that it works just like React documentation says – `useMemo` "saves" us from unwanted re-calculations (when component re-render is caused by something else like prop changes etc). But re-calculation still happens even if a value repeats itself (like `setA(10)`, then `setA(2)`, then again `setA(10)`).

Suppose `useMemo` is doing "classic" memoization, then on the third time instead of recalculating the value, it should be taken from the cache. **Does `useMemo` actually memoize (with caching) or is it only preventing unwanted recalculation like when component re-renders but dependencies did not change?**

Comment: Did you read the documentation, specifically the [caveats](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#caveats)? The function provided to `useMemo` is not guaranteed to be invoked only when dependencies change.

Comment: React will throw away the cache if the deps change (so 10, 2, 10 would be a change). Docs: "On every subsequent render, React will compare the dependencies with the dependencies you passed during the last render. If none of the dependencies have changed (compared with Object.is), useMemo will return the value you already calculated before. Otherwise, React will re-run your calculation and return the new value.

In other words, useMemo caches a calculation result between re-renders until its dependencies change."

Comment: @Wing Thank you for your help! Question about how useMemo works has been answered. Here is new question focused on my code samples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145420/how-does-useeffect-decide-if-should-passed-effect-function-be-called

Comment: I've updated your question so it's more focused. When I have some time, I'll look at your new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ##### Understanding of `useMemo` (does `useMemo` actually memoize?)

Yes, `useMemo` does memoize.

> ##### I am trying to figure out if `useMemo` has a cache table that maps dependencies with results.

No, `useMemo` does not use a cache table. Here's the source code for `useMemo` (comments pointing out important parts are from me (`// <--`)):

```
function mountMemo<T>( // <-- Runs on first `useMemo` call
  nextCreate: () => T,
  deps: Array<mixed> | void | null,
): T {
  const hook = mountWorkInProgressHook();
  const nextDeps = deps === undefined ? null : deps;
  if (shouldDoubleInvokeUserFnsInHooksDEV) {
    nextCreate();
  }
  const nextValue = nextCreate(); // <-- Calculate value
  hook.memoizedState = [nextValue, nextDeps]; // <-- Store value and dependencies
  return nextValue;
}

function updateMemo<T>( // <-- Runs on subsequent `useMemo` call
  nextCreate: () => T,
  deps: Array<mixed> | void | null,
): T {
  const hook = updateWorkInProgressHook();
  const nextDeps = deps === undefined ? null : deps;
  const prevState = hook.memoizedState;
  // Assume these are defined. If they're not, areHookInputsEqual will warn.
  if (nextDeps !== null) {
    const prevDeps: Array<mixed> | null = prevState[1];
    if (areHookInputsEqual(nextDeps, prevDeps)) { // <-- Compare dependencies
      return prevState[0]; // <-- If dependencies are equal return previous state
    }
  }
  if (shouldDoubleInvokeUserFnsInHooksDEV) {
    nextCreate();
  }
  const nextValue = nextCreate(); // <-- Otherwise, re-calculate
  hook.memoizedState = [nextValue, nextDeps]; // <-- Store value and dependencies (overwriting the last state)
  return nextValue;
}
```

– [react/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js:L2604-L2638](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b775564d35d6fe9f9acead0f380bbc86bb6bdd2c/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L2604-L2638)

It stores the calculated value and dependencies in an array which gets passed to *future calls of `useMemo`*. In the *next call of `useMemo`*, a comparison is made between the dependencies. If they are equal, then the last calculated result is returned. If they are not equal, then the value is re-calculated.

> ##### Does `useMemo` actually memoize (with caching) or is it only preventing unwanted recalculation like when component re-renders but dependencies did not change?

These two aren't mutually exclusive. It is doing both. It's just the cache is very small – it only holds the last result before getting invalidated when the dependencies change.

> Suppose `useMemo` is doing "classic" memoization, then on the third time instead of recalculating the value, it should be taken from the cache.

Drawing from my previous statement and the above quote from your question, I think the idea of a "classic memoization" needs to be examined. There **isn't** such thing as "classic" memoization. There are only strategies which must be chosen depending on the use-case. This quote from the Wikipedia page nicely suggests this as well:

> The set of remembered associations may be a fixed-size set controlled by a replacement algorithm or a fixed set, depending on the nature of the function and its use.

Having a cache has a trade-off – while it saves memory required for computation and time from having to calculate things, it requires memory for storing old values. So with this knowledge, you'll need to decide if `useMemo` is a suitable tool. If your use-case requires you to have expensive operations based on versions of state older than the previous version, then `useMemo` may not be for you. I imagine most use-cases won't be like this so `useMemo` is valuable as a tool in those cases. As with all performance optimisations, start with measuring first. Get familiar with the [performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) and your browser's memory or profiler tools.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll read into Performance API.
Your answer helped me to understand how does useMemo work. I'll accept this answer and create new question more focused on my last two questions.

Comment: Here is new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145420/how-does-useeffect-decide-if-should-passed-effect-function-be-called

Answer (score 1):

reading through their documentation and putting these lines together really looks to indicate that it is only for the most recent value based on the direct dependencies changing:

> "...React will call your function during the initial render. On next
> renders, React will return the same value again if the dependencies
> have not changed since the last render. Otherwise, it will call
> calculateValue, return its result, and store it so it can be reused
> later."
>
> "...React will compare each dependency with its previous value using the
> Object.is comparison."
>
> "...During next renders, it will either return an already stored value
> from the last render (if the dependencies haven’t changed), or call
> calculateValue again, and return the result that calculateValue has
> returned."

to your point it is like memoization definition from wikipedia but not exact as it isn't as smart as an actual cache like map

also would be a fantastic feature for them to add!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I agree. Currently it looks like we should write our custom memo function if we want to have wikipedia-defined memoization. So it would be cool if they add this feature too.

Comment: Note (also mentioned in my answer): the behaviour of `useMemo` and the Wikipedia definition are **not** in contradiction. A cache size of 1 is still a cache. A cache with a simple storage mechanism like an array is still a cache. It is basic but it does solve most use cases you'll come across and React isn't a caching library so I think it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, useMemo in React works by storing the dependencies (deps) in a reference each time it is executed. It constantly monitors these dependencies for any changes. If there are changes or if the dependencies are undefined, useMemo will re-run the provided callback function and store its results for future use. However, if the dependencies remain unchanged, useMemo returns the previously memoized value, optimizing performance.

here is my implementation of useMemo which does the same thing.

```
const useMemo = (callback, deps) => {
    const depsRef = useRef(undefined);
    const memoizedValueRef = useRef(undefined);

    if (deps !== undefined && !Array.isArray(deps)) {
        throw new Error("deps can only be undefined or an array");
    }

    const isNewDepsChangedToArray = depsRef.current === undefined && Array.isArray(deps);
    const isNewDepsUndefiend = !deps;
    const isShallowDifferent = Array.isArray(depsRef.current) && Array.isArray(deps) && (deps.length !== depsRef.current.length || deps.some((dep, i) => dep !== depsRef.current[i]));

    if (isNewDepsChangedToArray || isNewDepsUndefiend || isShallowDifferent) {
        memoizedValueRef.current = callback();
    }

    depsRef.current = Array.isArray(deps) ? [...deps] : undefined;

    return memoizedValueRef.current;
};
```