# How does useEffect decide if should passed effect function be called?

Tags: reactjs, optimization, react-hooks

Here are two code samples:

#1:

```
import { heavyCalculate } from './helpers';

...

const [data, setData] = useState(INITIAL_DATA); // consider data is large object

const dataDependentValue = useMemo(() => {
  console.log("recalculating dataDependentValue");
  return heavyCalculate(data); // just some "heavy" calculations
}, [data]);

...
```

#2:

```
// Custom hook that returns value calculated by processor function whenever deps (dependencies array) changes
// Of course, hook is declared outside of react component
const useDependentValue = (processor, deps) => {
  console.log("Call `useDependentValue`", { deps });

  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    console.log("Initial `useState` call");
    return processor();
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateValue = () => {
      setValue(() => {
        console.log("Update");
        return processor();
      });
    };

    updateValue();
  }, deps);

  return value;
};
```

```
import { useDependentValue } from './hooks'; 
import { heavyCalculate } from './helpers';

...

const [data, setData] = useState(INITIAL_DATA); // consider data is large object

const dataDependentValue = useDependentValue(() => {
  console.log("recalculating dataDependentValue");
  return heavyCalculate(data); // just some "heavy" calculations
}, [data]);

...
```

This is my previous question (might help to understand context of my quesions): [Understanding of useMemo (does useMemo actually memoize?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144467/understanding-of-usememo-does-usememo-actually-memoize)

My questions are:
**Are there any cases when useDependentValue should be used instead of useMemo for better (CPU time / memory) performance?**

**How does useEffect (with non-empty dependencies array) decide if should passed effect function be called? Does this work the same way as useMemo (comparing deps values between last two renders). Or is there something else?**

I am asking this, because if useEffect also keeps copy of dependencies of last render, then I don't see much usefulness of my useDependentValue hook. On the other hand, if useEffect does not cache dependencies and does not compare new dependencies to previous, then maybe useDependentValue could work faster for  dependencies with very large objects, comparsion of which could be slow.

Comment: What is `useDependentValue` trying to do? I think that you might be misunderstanding what it is doing, so just trying to get some insight into your current understanding.

Comment: @Wing We always can create derived values like so: const aSquare = a ** 2; But this way aSquare is going to be recalculated every time component re-renders. What I am trying to do with useDependentValue is to skip unnecessary recalculations. It's totally doable with useMemo, so from there starts my question...

Comment: Ok, I'm just trying to piece together different pieces of information like what you've written in the question, the code you have, and your answer to my question in this thread.

Comment: `useDependentValue` right now doesn't behave it the way you want it to. However I feel like your question is asking about details for `useEffect` . Essentially, it's a bit confusing (kinda like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)). I think it might be worth editing your question so that it's clear what you're trying to achieve. Your "`setA(10)`, then `setA(2)`, then again `setA(10)`" example from your linked question is really good. If that's what you want to achieve, I'd edit reword your question about that.

Comment: My linked question helped me to understand that useMemo compares dependencies values only between new and prev render. So now I am trying to understand is there any point to prefer useDependentValue, cause it feels very similar to useMemo. 
And no, I am not trying to achieve any kind of memoization for "10, 2, 10" case. I understand that just have to write my own memoization for that case if I want to.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` and `useMemo` are used for different purposes.

`useEffect` is to rerun a certain logic on a generalized purpose, such as re-fetch some data from API when a variable in the dependency list is updated (such as `query`) and isn't used for performance optimization like `useMemo`. Speaking of `useMemo`...

`useMemo` is used for web performance optimization, so some variable doesn't need to be reevaluated again on another re-render depending on the dependency list.

In short, `useEffect` is regularly used to enable some functionality for the components, whereas `useMemo` is purely for web performance optimization which can be completely optional.

> I am asking this, because if useEffect also keeps a copy of dependencies of the last render, then I don't see much usefulness of my useDependentValue hook.

This simply means you probably don't need to have a `useEffect` or a different variable is needs to be added inside of the dependency list, so the  `dataDependentValue` will be updated more to your use case.

For example, given your component is about to re-render, should you make another API request to whatever service you need to reach if your search query remains unchanged from the previous render?

> On the other hand, if useEffect does not cache dependencies and does not compare new dependencies to previous ones, then maybe useDependentValue could work faster for dependencies with very large objects, the comparison of which could be slow.

Usually, the simple comparison should be way faster than whatever you are going to run inside the `useEffect` or `useMemo`. However, you definitely should avoid adding huge size of variables, or non-memoized variables into the dependency list to make either `useEffect` or `useMemo` not doing their job by still running whatever code is inside them on every render.

A good resource to read is this Remove Unnecessary Object/Function Dependency from the list https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#removing-unnecessary-object-dependencies