# Updating Single Data Point in React-Plotly without Re-Rendering Entire Plot

Tags: reactjs, plotly, plotly-react

I am using [React-Plotly](https://plotly.com/javascript/react/) to make a scatter plot in a dashboard. There are sibling components to this scatter plot where a user can select a "unit". When a user selects a unit in one of these sibling components, I store the unit ID in global state, and the scatter plot accesses that ID to determine what type of marker to use for each unit.

My dilemma is that the underlying units don't change very frequently, but the selected unit does change frequently. This causes performance issues because multiple scatter plots with tens of thousands of markers re-render every time a new unit is selected. I just need one or two markers to re-render - the one that is newly selected, and any potential previously selected marker.

Is there a way in React-Plotly, or a different charting library, to update one marker without re-rendering the entire scatter plot component? I wish I could feed `<Plot />` an array of children marker components that could each access the `selectedUnitID` state without having to map over all the units and create a new data array each time. That would save me from accessing `selectedUnitID` in the parent, causing the re-render. I do something similar when making maps in React-Leaflet, but I haven't found a comparable solution for charting libraries. They all seem to require passing an array of objects, which is recreated with every unavoidable re-render in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
// ScatterPlot.tsx
export const ScatterPlot = (): JSX.Element => {
  const units = useSelector(selectUnits); // Doesn't change often
  const selectedUnitID = useSelector(selectSelectedUnitID); // Changes often

  const data = units.map(u => {
  return {
    x: u.x,
    y: u.y,
    type: "scatter",
    mode: "lines+markers",
    marker: selectedUnitID === u.id ? selectedMarker : normalMarker
  };

  return <Plot layout={{ width: 320, height: 240, title: "Units Plot" }} data={data} />
};
```

I have considered storing the array in a `ref.current` and passing the ref down to a memoized `<Plot />` component since that will be preserved between re-renders, but that seems a little hacky. I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here.

Edit:

If I alter the units array in place, I can memoize the `<Plot />` element so it doesn't re-render since the array reference won't change. However, then the plot doesn't change when it needs to, so I use the [revision prop](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js?tab=readme-ov-file#basic-props). But then I'm back at square-one because `revision` will change often, re-rendering the entire plot. What I'm really looking for is the ability to re-render just one or two markers.

Answer (score 1):

if i get you correctly ,you want to avoid unnecessary computing on function call on every time there is slight change

in the below block, the `UseMemo` will compare these given dependencies with the previous render state and if there is no changes between any of these dependencies then the `useMemo` will not call the function again so nothing will render again.

so try the following block that use `useMemo`

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';

export const ScatterPlot = (): JSX.Element => {
  const units = useSelector(selectUnits); // Doesn't change often
  const selectedUnitID = useSelector(selectSelectedUnitID); // Changes often

  const data = useMemo(() => {
    return units.map(u => {
      return {
        x: u.x,
        y: u.y,
        type: "scatter",
        mode: "lines+markers",
        marker: selectedUnitID === u.id ? selectedMarker : normalMarker
      };
    });
  }, [units, selectedUnitID]);

  return <Plot layout={{ width: 320, height: 240, title: "Units Plot" }} data={data} />;
};
```

but if you pass an empty array []  then the useMemo will only execute the function once on the very first render of the component, and it will keep these value for rest of the lifecycle for this given component .

please read [understanding-of-usememo-does-usememo-actually-memoize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144467/understanding-of-usememo-does-usememo-actually-memoize)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not sure this solves my problem though. `useMemo` will run every time `selectedUnitID` changes, which is often. My problem is that I have thousands of markers in a plot, but only one or two of them needs to change. I'm getting close to a solution that memoizes `<Plot />` and adds and removes a "selected marker" using `selectedUnitID` to the units array in place. However, now I'm having the opposite problem where the plot doesn't update enough. I think I need [the revision prop](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js?tab=readme-ov-file#refreshing-the-plot):